# Database column for locks vs native locking functions

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, locking

Normally whenever I've needed to lock a row in a database, I've used a dedicated column of type bool that I've toggled on and off. I've recently learned that there are built in locking functions in various databases such as MySQL. What advantages are there over using these native locking features over using a column for locking and unlocking.

Comment: Aside from the fact that you are re-inventing the wheel, and probably doing a worse job than MySQL?

Comment: Concurrency safety is your friend. Writing a lock column is not safe.  There's a timing issue with multiple connections hitting the same database, depending on the storage engine in use.  If the engine does table locking on updates, you could get away with it i suppose. You could in theory have a reader hit the database while you're doing the update and have a problem.

Comment: What's more: you cannot enforce the use of the column. You can update/overwrite the data using SQL directly without ever looking at that column. A lock held by the database engine can *not* be worked around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Readability.  Nobody would be expecting your 'locking boolean'.
2. Race conditions.  Without a lock, how do you atomically update your 'locking boolean'?
3. Performance.  You're probably doing three updates (lock, update, unlock), when only one is needed.

Ok, I'm tired now.